# CakePHP3.4でファイルを作成しつつダウンロードを行うとヘッダーエラーが発生する

Tags: php, cakephp

お世話になります。

現在CakePHP3.4でダウンロードの処理を下記のようなコードで作成したのですが
エラーが発生し、画面上に出力内容が表示されるという問題が発生しています。
ヘッダーエラーを発生させずに処理をさせる方法とかはないでしょうか？
※php.iniのbuffering_outputは4096になっており、ダウンロードするファイルサイズが
　このサイズを超過するとエラーが発生するのは分かりました。
 （onにすると大容量ファイルになった場合メモリを食いつぶしてメモリエラーになったため、NGでした。）

[xxxController.php]

```
public function download()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->type('csv');
    $this->response->download('test.txt');

    $fp = fopen('php://output','w');
    stream_filter_append($fp, 'convert.iconv.UTF-8/CP932', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);

    $user_list=array('value1','value2','value3','value4','value5','value6');

    for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
        $outStr = implode("\t", $user_list)."\r\n";
        fwrite($fp,$outStr);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

[エラー内容]
Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=/var/www/html/xxx/src/Controller/xxxController.php line=56 [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 48]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/xxx/src/Controller/xxxController.php:56) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 148]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/xxx/src/Controller/xxxController.php:56) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 178]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/xxx/src/Controller/xxxController.php:56) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 178]

[追記]
実際に行いたいこととしましては、dbなどから取得した情報をサーバ上に
ファイルとして出力せずに、ユーザーのブラウザに対して出力（ダウンロードさせる）
という処理になります。
そのため、サーバに置いてあるファイルをダウンロードするのではなく
ファイルを作成しつつエラー無くダウンロードさせる。という部分が知りたいです。
（現状、そのつもりで処理を書いていますがヘッダーエラーが発生してしまう。）

Comment: 直接出力するのではなく、response->withBody() に CallbackStream を使用したらいかがでしょうか。 https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/controllers/request-response.html#Cake\Http\Response::withBody

Comment: 回答をくださったのに、申し訳ありません。質問内容を訂正いたしましたが、今回はファイルを生成しつつ、ダウンロードを行いたいため、頂いた内容ではできなさそうです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

動的にレスポンスを返したい場合は、 `Cake\Http\Response::withBody()` と `\Cake\Http\CallbackStream` を使用します。

リクエストとレスポンスオブジェクト ボディーの設定 | CakePHP Cookbook
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/controllers/request-response.html#id18

CallbackStream に、処理したい内容をクロージャーで記述します。

```
public function download()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $stream = new \Cake\Http\CallbackStream(function () {
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        stream_filter_append($fp, 'convert.iconv.UTF-8/CP932//TRANSLIT', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);

        $user_list = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6'];

        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
            $outStr = implode("\t", $user_list) . "\r\n";
            fwrite($fp, $outStr);
        }
    });

    return $this->response
            ->withType('csv')
            ->withDownload('test.txt')
            ->withBody($stream);
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。記載して頂いた方法で、ダウンロード処理実現できました。CallbackStreamの中にクロージャーで処理を記述するのですね。ただ、重たいファイルをDL中に別controllerが動かないという点があったため、もし解決手段があればご教授くださると助かります。